# Firefox and Seleniumwire not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, amazon-ec2, seleniumwire

I'm trying to run Firefox with Seleniumwire on an AWS EC2 instance. Here's my current configuration:

- ubuntu==20.4
- selenium-wire==4.3.0
- python==3.8.10
- geckodriver==0.29.1
- ChromeDriver==94.0.4606.81
- 64-bit (Arm)

I've installed ChromeDriver with `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver` and geckodriver with `sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver`.

Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

d = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
d.get("https://google.com")
print(d.requests)
```

The problem: `d.requests` returns `[]`, which is unexpected behavior. I know there's been issues posted about `driver.requests` returning an empty list, but the recommended solutions haven't worked on my setup. Also `print(d.page_source)` works fine, which leads me to think there's some incorrect proxy configuration. Also, I isolated this problem to Firefox, since the same code works on Chrome (with Firefox swapped out for Chrome); that is, `d.requests` contains a non-empty list of requests. I would use Chrome, but the scope of my project requires Firefox.

Here're some steps I've taken to debug:

- Setting the port explicitly using `selenium_options={"port": 4444}`, where `4444` is taken from the localhost output of `geckodriver` on the command line.
- Adding a proxy using the following format:

```
options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': 'http://myusername:password@myproxyserver.com:123456', 
            'https': 'http://myusername:password@myproxyserver.com:123456',
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
        }  
    }
```

- Re-installing and re-running all my scripts on a new EC2 instance.
- Specifying a different `tmp` directory, per [this](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/131) issue

I have yet to try different versions of `geckodriver` and `selenium-wire`, but I suspect that's not the issue.

Any suggestions on debugging would be greatly appreciated.